# Collection does not work if used inside ng-if, but work with ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just upgraded Angular from 1.4.8 to 1.6.4 in my application and I am facing an issue with a select menu that gets the data from a controller variable.

html:

```
<div id='main_app_header' ng-if="ctrl.shouldShowHeader">
  <accounts-directive></accounts-directive>
</div>
```

The accounts directive has the select menu.

```
<div class="account-selector" ng-class="{'account-selector-disabled': haCtrl.accounts.length == 1}">
  <select id="account-select" ng-model="haCtrl.current"
      ng-options="account as account.name for account in haCtrl.accounts track by account.id"
      ng-change="haCtrl.changeAccount()"
      ng-disabled="haCtrl.accounts.length == 1">
  </select>
</div>
```

When inspecting controllers all data is there. If i change the `ng-if` to `ng-show` everything works fine. I do not want to use `ng-show as not wanted to increase the number of watchers in the DOM. Is there something wrong I am doing?

Directive Code:

```
"use strict";

(function() {

var AccountsDirective = function() {

return {

  restrict: 'E',

  replace: true,

  templateUrl: "app/components/header/account/view.html",

  controller: 'HeaderAccountCtrl as haCtrl'

};

};

  angular.module('mainNgApp').directive('AccountsDirective', AccountsDirective);

})();
```

Controller Code:

```
"use strict";

(function() {

var HeaderAccountCtrl = function(
$scope,
atomico,
events,
userState
) {

var _this = this;

atomico.ready(function() {
  _this.accounts = atomico.metadata['accounts'];
  _this.current  = atomico.metadata['account'];
});

_this.changeAccount = function(){
  atomico.metadata['account'] = _this.current;

  userState.setActiveAccountId(_this.current.id, function() {
    events.account.change(_this.current);
  });
};

};

HeaderAccountCtrl.$inject = [
'$scope',
'atomico',
'events',
'userState'
];

angular.module('mainNgApp').controller('HeaderAccountCtrl', HeaderAccountCtrl);

})();
```

The errors i get when switching to `ng-if` are as  below:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
    at updateOptions (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:30346)
    at Object.ngOptionsPostLink (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:30249)
    at angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:1347
    at invokeLinkFn (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:10427)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:9816)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:9056)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:9810)
    at delayedNodeLinkFn (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:10177)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:9056)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:9059) ""
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at SelectController.writeNgOptionsValue [as writeValue] (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:30117)
    at Object.ngModelCtrl.$render (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:32811)
    at ngModelWatch (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:28960)
    at Scope.$digest (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:17992)
    at Scope.$apply (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:18270)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:27000)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:5227)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:4879)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at SelectController.writeNgOptionsValue [as writeValue] (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:30117)
    at Object.ngModelCtrl.$render (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:32811)
    at angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:30156
    at Scope.$digest (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:18000)
    at Scope.$apply (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:18270)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:27000)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:5227)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:4879)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
    at nodeName_ (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:886)
    at getBooleanAttrName (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:3497)
    at Attributes.$set (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:8650)
    at ngBooleanAttrWatchAction (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:22801)
    at Scope.$digest (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:18000)
    at Scope.$apply (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:18270)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular-1.6.4.self-cbf63df….js?body=1:27000)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:5227)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:4879)
```

Comment: Assume the closing `div` being incorrect is a typo in the post. Can you add your directive/component definition? It may help.

Comment: Sure thing Matt

Comment: Outline of the `HeaderAccountCtrl` important too. It's suggesting that the `accounts` property is not defined yet. Can you list too?

Comment: @MattTester Just added the controller too.

Answer (score 0):

The error is suggesting that `accounts` is not defined. Looking at your controller code, this is set via the `atomico.ready()` function which is where the problem is going to be.

`ngShow` only hides elements in the DOM whereas `ngIf` will add and remove them.

What is happening is that the `ngIf` is adding your component into the DOM, and it is only at this point that the controller is instantiated. However the `atomico.ready()` is not being called because (I assume) it has already been called when the page was loaded.

I'm not sure what the `atomico` service/factory is, but I'd suggest passing arguments to the directive instead of using it in the directive. That way the page can handle the `atomico.ready()` callback instead, and pass the results to the directive when needed.

So, make use of the `bindToController` parameter:

```
var AccountsDirective = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "app/components/header/account/view.html",
        controller: 'HeaderAccountCtrl as haCtrl',
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
             accounts: "<"
        }
    };
};
```

And pass in using:

```
<accounts-directive accounts="ctrl.accounts"></accounts-directive>
```

Comment: Matt I will try and use this version and if it works I will accept the answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: It did not work still, Moved it out of atomico.ready() and used bind to controller, still the same issue. Not sure what is going on there.